# AppDelegate create NSView, draw NSImage to NSView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, nsimage

I'm currently trying to create a simple app that accesses a folder and randomly loads images and displays them in its window. 
As expected I'm struggling right away.

I have to files:

- AppDelegate.h
- AppDelegate.m

.h is empty, .m contains all the code.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (strong) NSImage *image;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    NSRect frame = [_window frame];
    NSView *view = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];

    NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pathtoimage" ofType:@"jpg"];
    _image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

@end
```

So how do I now set the view to my window and how do I then draw the image to the view?

EDIT:
Changed code to this, still nothing displayed except an empty window.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    NSRect frame = [_window frame];
    NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"/Users/Me/Documents/Me/Art/picturename" ofType:@"png"];
    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

    NSImageView *myImage = [[NSImageView alloc] init];
    [myImage setFrame:frame];
    [myImage setImage:image];
    [self.window.contentView addSubview:myImage];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

@end
```

EDIT2:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    NSRect frame = [_window frame];
    //NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"doorTech" ofType:@"jpg"];
    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/Adrian/Documents/Adrian/Art/desertMovie.jpg"];

    if (image == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Image is nil");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Image is not nil");
    }
    NSImageView *myImage = [[NSImageView alloc] init];
    [myImage setFrame:frame];
    [myImage setImage:image];
    [self.window.contentView addSubview:myImage];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

@end
```

Comment: You have to add the view as a subview via [self.window.contentView addSubview:view]. As for the image, unless you have a specific reason why you need to draw the image, you should just load it into an NSImageView and add the image view to a view using the same steps.

Comment: Have you verified that image is not nil?

Comment: You are right, Image is nil. But why? the path is correct.

Comment: Now it's not nil. It can only load .jpg, wtf!? Butt still nothing presented on my window :(
I have no view maybe thats the problem? I got an empty window which has as a delegate AppDelegate.h/.m. Thats the only files I got. I updated the code as well.

Comment: Is there a particular reason not to add the image view in Interface Builder?

Comment: Yeah I want to know how you do it programmatically. GEEZUZ! There has to be a way!!

Comment: Ok, it works. Problem is the image is just drawn anywhere. I have to resize the window to make it visible. Already did [_imageView setBoundsOrigin:NSZeroPoint];